# Copy Constructors and calling functions

Tags: c++, function, constructor, copy

I'm trying to call an accessor function in a copy constructor but it's not working.  Here's an example of my problem:

A.h

```
class A {

public:
    //Constructor
    A(int d);
    //Copy Constructor
    A(const A &rhs);

    //accessor for data
    int getData();

    //mutator for data
    void setData(int d);

private:
    int data;
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

//Constructor
A::A(int d) {
    this->setData(d);
}

//Copy Constructor
A::A(const A &rhs) {
    this->setData(rhs.getData()); 
}

//accessor for data
int A::getData() {
    return data;
}

//mutator for data
void A::setData(int d) {
    data = d;
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
error: passing 'const A' as 'this' argument of 'int A::getData()' discards qualifiers
```

If I change `rhs.getData()` to `rhs.data`, then the constructor works fine.  Am I not allowed to call functions in a copy constructor?  Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to use an accessor for this. A class is automatically a friend of itself. So object X can read the private members of object Y if they are the same type. It is assumed that the author of the code knows what he is doing and the implementation details and thus there is no need to protect yourself from yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is `rhs` is declared as `const`, but `getData()` isn't, so it could be modifying `rhs` when you call it even though `rhs` is supposedly const. As `getData()` is an accessor, it should be `const` too:

```
//accessor for data
int getData() const;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your "accessor" can only be called on non-const objects, because it isn't marked const. You should declare it:

```
int getData() const;
```

Then you're allowed to call it on `rhs`, which is a const reference.